# Compile IMAP with certain PHP API version for MAMP

Tags: osx, software-installation, php

I've installed MAMP on Mac OS X (where PHP 5.3.15 with API version `20090626` is installed), but IMAP there is without SSL support.

As long as MAMP using PHP v5.4.4 (API version `20100525`) I've downloaded its sources.

But. When I type `phpize` the `phpize` from Mac OS X called, not from MAMP (maybe because it's installed in system when MAMP has PHP libs inside itself). So how do I compile IMAP sources with API version of MAMP's PHP?

Answer (score 0):

So I had to upgrade Mac OS X's PHP to 5.4.4. Don't know if I could do it another way.